# Criar linhas a partir do índice de uma série ou dataframe Python

Tags: python

Criei esse dataframe:

```
x = [1,3,5,8,10,15,4,5,6,8,23,12,28]  
x = pd.DataFrame(x)
```

Criei o seguinte dataframe:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Criei um novo dataframe com o seguinte codigo:

```
z = []
for i in range(len(x)):
    z.append(x[i:i+3])
```

E obtive o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu gostaria de criar um Dataframe onde, invés da serie ir do "`i:i+3`" seria algo como "i:i==5", ou seja o valor final não seria três índices para frente, mas o valor "5" da coluna. Não sei qual código se utiliza para obter essa lista

Comment: Qual o problema ai para estar pendente? ja modifiquei e não adiantou nd